# query dynamic link to retrieve json file using cURL and php

Tags: php, json, curl, dynamic, blockchain

Hello I am trying to query the **[site URL](https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&address=1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq)** which will return a dynamic json file containing the following information...

```
{"input_address":"1BEgj5JUUsUz91bR9F6q6YoUPgtAGWAZg9","destination":"1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq","fee_percent":0}
```

I need to extract the input_address from that json file. This is probably easy although I am very new to php, here is what i have located in xx.php...

```
<?php
$root_url = 'https://blockchain.info/api/receive?method=create&address=1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq';
$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)':
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type:application/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $root_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPY_USERAGENT, $agent);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$gg = json_decode($result);
var_dump(json_decode($result));
$hh = var_dump($gg['input_address']);
//$zz = json_decode($result);
echo 'blah:'. $gg;
echo 'hh:'. $hh;
?>
```

When I go to `xx.php` it is returning a blank page and I thought it should return a page that echos the contents of the entire json file? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the curl request is unsuccessful... try `echo curl_error($ch)` after the `curl_exec` line to see what the error is while trying to retrieve the url...

Comment: This still gives me nothing, still a blank page loads.

Comment: Ok, there are a couple of issues going on here... First, the `$agent = ...` line is terminated by a `:` in your code, change it to a semi-colon `;`. Next it seems you have error_reporting turned off, you will have to turn it on. Check this link for pointers on how to turn it on properly: [Turning Error Reporting On](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm). Next, it seems that you are using the json_decode return value as an array when it actually returns an object. You can force it to return an array using the 2nd param like this: `json_decode($result, true)`